# Possible to set dynamic values for versionCode in defaultConfig?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

By default, Gradle `build.gradle` usually looks like  this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz.android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
           ...
```

Is there a way to make `defaultConfig.versionCode` and `defaultConfig.versionName` dynamic, instead of static?

By dynamic I meant to bind them to the `Manifest` so these two values update when the same Manifest values update.

Comment: but it works in exactly opposite way: manifest is builded with values from build.gradle ... could you add explanation why you need this?

Comment: @Selvin I did NOT know that. I recently moved to Gradle and continued setting these values in the Manifest manually. Please add this as a reply and I will mark it as an answer. It will help others. You may expand the reply if you want :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in Gradle we don't have to touch `Manifest`. All we have to do is to set Gradle and it will set `Manifest`. That is the main reason why Gradle projects don't have set these values in `Manifest` by default.